# rewrite url for search option

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

i want to rewrite the url for search option..currently my search option working fine..but i want to customize the url and
this is my html script

```
<form name="search2" method="post" action="my-city.php">      
<select name="countryname">
<option value="usa">usa</option>
<option value="aus">aus</option>
</select>

<select name="num">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
```

Current result:
https://mydomain.com/ezhil/mysite/code/my-city.php

Expected result (for example if i choose `countryname=usa`, `num=1`, `day=2`
the url should be like this):
https://mydomain.com/ezhil/mysite/code/my-city/usa/1/2

Comment: You need javascript for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have at the top of `my-city.php` the following:

```
<?php

if(array_key_exists("countryname",$_POST) and array_key_exists("num",$_POST) and array_key_exists("day",$_POST))
{
    preg_match("/^([a-z]+)$/",$_POST["countryname"],$countryname);
    $num = intval($_POST["num"]);
    $day = intval($_POST["day"]);
    if($contryname[1] != "" and $num > 0 and day > 0)
        Header("Location: http://mydomain.com/ezhil/mysite/code/my-city/".$countryname[1]."/".$num."/".$day);
}
?>
```

Plus you need to fix your html code as follows:

```
<form name="search2" method="post" action="my-city.php">      
<select name="countryname">
<option value="usa">usa</option>
<option value="aus">aus</option>
</select>

<select name="num">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
```

Comment: its not working i got https://mydomain.com/ezhil/mysite/code/my-city//0/0 and displays 404 error

Comment: sorry... that comes from my tests

Comment: what are the changes you made in html

Comment: the option close tags for the first num's and day's option

Comment: and the type of the submit

Comment: its not working again same problem i got mydomain.com/ezhil/mysite/code/my-city//0/0 and displays 404 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56275/discussion-between-clami219-and-ezhil).

Comment: its not working..the page just redirected to my-city.php thats all.. nothing happened..

Comment: The problem is not with the redirect, but with the parameters, which do not get where they should... try putting a `print_r($_POST)` and see what it's printed in the page.